# Django pass data from form to template

Tags: django, forms, templates, view

I'd like to pass few informations from form (datas from 2 DateFields) to my template. Right now my `form` looks like this:

```
class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    start = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(), initial=date.today())
    end = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(),initial=date.today())
    type = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=ACTIVITY_CHOICES, initial=RUNNING)
```

I'd like to pass `start` & `end` fields to my `template` which looks like this:

```
<body>
{{ request.session.temp_data }}

<div id="header">
    <div id="navbar">
        <h1>Raport za okres {{ temp_data.start }}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

So after putting it all together, it should show something like `Raport za okres 2.12.2014` but it shows only `Raport za okres`. I was looking through docs, other StackOverflow topics, but I couldn't find (or understand) how it should be done. If needed, here's my `view` that uses my `form` and `template`:

```
def ReportRequest(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ReportForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        usrname = request.user
        q = Training.objects.filter(user=usrname, date__range=[form.cleaned_data['start'], form.cleaned_data['end']], type=form.cleaned_data['type'])
        quantity = q.count()
        if quantity == 0:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/notrainings/')
        avg_length = q.aggregate(Avg('length'))
        avg_distance = q.aggregate(Avg('distance'))
        avg_calories = q.aggregate(Avg('caloriesBurnt'))
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/report')
    else:
        return render_to_response('reportform.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    form = ReportForm()
    return render_to_response('reportform.html',{'form':form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.request.session['temp_data'] = form.cleaned_data
    return super(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="reportform.html"), self).form_valid(form)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I need to use both `start` & `end` field in my template

**SOLVED thanks to abhishekgarg:**
Instead of using `HttpResponseRedirect` I've used return
 `render_to_response('report.html', {'form':form, 'start':start, 'end':end, 'athlete':athlete}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`
 like abhishekgarg suggested. I'll leave this, maybe someone will get stuck on similiar problem

Comment: why can't you just send the data like you are sending the form `{'form':form, 'start': start, 'end': end}`

Comment: @abhishekgarg, but where should I put it? I'm using `HttpResponseRedirect` to actually go to the template. Should I use `render_to_response` instead?

Comment: your question is not clear, do you want to pass those values once you get a valid request?

Comment: if you do want to put some data in httpredirect as well, you can do something like `/my_redirect/?start=start&end=end` and those values will come there as GET data

Comment: do you just want to render that form in the template?

Comment: Yes. I'm completely new to Django, but I've changed `return HttpResponseRedirect('/report')` to `return render_to_response('report.html', {'form':form, 'start':start, 'end':end,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))` as you suggested with defining `start` and `end` field andit works like a charm. Thank you for that answer.

Comment: @abhishekgarg, I just wanted to get datas from form and show them on my template (just render, not doing anything more with them)

Comment: No problem, we are here to help ;)